# How to send value from controller to ejs without reloading page : Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wanna send the value from controller to ejs file without reloading page when I summit input in ejs. This is code in ejs file.

```
<html>
    <p class="topicCard3">History Of PM2.5 Values ​​In <%= country %></p>
        <form method="POST" action="/historyPM2.5">
            <input class="inputCountry" name='country' placeholder="enter country name">
            <button class="submitButton">SUBMIT</button>
        </form>
    <p>
<html>
```

and this is code in controller.js

```
exports.historyPm = function(req,res) {
    country = req.body.country
    res.render('home',{
        'country': country
    })
}
```

I need to process something in controller then send result to ejs for showing. Now, I send the value input from ejs to controller and then click summit button the page will reload.  Thank for helping.

Comment: you need to use ajax for making a request to an endpoint and get data...

Answer (score 1):

You need just to prevent the form from reloading the page when clicking on submit button. We can achieve that by multiple techniques and here below a jQuery

example:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
    $('form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // prevents page reloading
       // api request
       return false;
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <script>
    $(document)
    .on('click', 'form button[type=submit]', function(e) {

        //write your ajax code here

        e.preventDefault(); //stop submitting the form to avoid reload
    });
  <script>
```